# Javascript map api data to new object

Tags: javascript

My application receives data from an API and has this structure:

```
const searchFilters = [
    {
      "filter": "Make",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Chevy",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Ford",
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Honda",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "filter": "Color",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Black",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "White",
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Red",
        }
      ]
    },
];
```

I need to create a new object with this structure:

```
const make = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "Chevy",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "Ford",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "Honda",
    }
];
```

Here is what I have so far:

```js
const searchFilters = [ { "filter": "Make", "values": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Chevy", }, { "id": 2, "name": "Ford", }, { "id": 3, "name": "Honda", } ] }, { "filter": "Color", "values": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Black", }, { "id": 2, "name": "White", }, { "id": 3, "name": "Red", } ] }, ];


const make = searchFilters
  ?.filter(f => f.filter === "Make")
  .map(v => v.values.map((value) => {
    return {
      id: value.id,
      label: value.name
    }
  }))
                
console.log(make);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Seems to work as you expect: https://jsbin.com/hasufuhudu/1/edit?js,console What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#flatMap`.

```js
const searchFilters=[{filter:"Make",values:[{id:1,name:"Chevy"},{id:2,name:"Ford"},{id:3,name:"Honda"}]},{filter:"Color",values:[{id:1,name:"Black"},{id:2,name:"White"},{id:3,name:"Red"}]},];
const make = searchFilters?.filter(f => f.filter === "Make")
  .flatMap(v => v.values.map(({id, name : label}) => ({id, label})));
console.log(make);
```